# Setting OnClickListener on the actionbar home icon makes the icon loose the press state

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Setting the following makes the home icon show a press state:

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

But, after setting OnClickListener the home icon stops showing the press state:

```
ImageView iconImage = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.home);
iconImage.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
```

Any idea on how to prevent disabling the press state?

Answer (score 8):

To handle the click on the `home` icon , you do not need to set `onClickListener`, you need to do the following..

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) { //app icon in action bar clicked; go back
        //do something
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: But I chose to do it this way. Any idea how to make the ImageView still show the press state?

Comment: I choose the listener way, because it is more straight forward and because onOptionsItemSelected was never invoked.

Comment: unfortunately i do not know how to show the press state..but the above method is the way mentioned in the documentaion..http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

Comment: when i use actionbar.setIcon(resId); this function is not working (I use setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Fragment fr;
      FragmentManager fm;
      Button btn1,btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
         actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        fm = getFragmentManager();


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     fr = new frag22();
                     FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                     ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fr);
                     ft.commit();

            }
        });
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) { //app icon in action bar clicked; go back
                //do something

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "set click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```